# Custom post type not showing in admin menu

Tags: custom-post-types

I made four custom post types. And I can't figure out, why the fourth one is not showing up in the admin menu.

her is the code:

drx_services.php:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'drx_services_post_type' );
    function drx_services_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'drx_services',
            array (
                'labels' => array (
                    'name' => __( 'Service-Angebote' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Service-Angebot' )
                ),
                'taxonomies' => array ('post_tag', 'category'),
                'public' => true,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-hammer',
                'has_archive' => true,
                'supports' => array ( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
                'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'service')
            )
        );
    }

include 'drx_srvcs_team.php';
include 'drx_srvcs_cafe.php';
include 'drx_srvcs_announcement.php';
```

drx_srvcs_team.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'drx_service_team_post_type' );
function drx_service_team_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'drx_service_team',
        array (
            'labels' => array (
                'name'                => _x( 'Service-Team', 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Service-Held', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Service-Team'),
                'all_items'           => __( 'Das Service-Team'),
                'view_item'           => __( 'Service Held anzeigen'),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Service-Held hinzufügen'),
                'add_new'             => __( 'Neuer Service-Held'),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Service-Held bearbeiten'),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Aktualisiere Service-Held'),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Service-Held suchen'),
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array ('post_tag', 'category'),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array ( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
            'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'service-heroes')
        )
    );
}
```

drx_srvcs_cafe.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'drx_service_cafe_post_type' );
function drx_service_cafe_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'drx_service_cafe',
        array (
            'labels' => array (
                'name'                => _x( 'Repair Cafés', 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Repair Café', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'Cafés'),
                'all_items'           => __( 'Alle Cafés'),
                'view_item'           => __( 'Café anzeigen'),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Café hinzufügen'),
                'add_new'             => __( 'Neues Café'),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Café bearbeiten'),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Aktualisiere Café'),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Café suchen'),
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array ('post_tag', 'category'),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array ( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
            'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'service-heroes')
        )
    );
}
```

drx_srvcs_announcement.php -> THIS is not showing!!

```
add_action( 'init', 'drx_srvcs_announcement_post_type' );
function drx_srvcs_announcement_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'drx_srvcs_announcement',
        array (
            'labels' => array (
                'name'                => _x( 'Termine', 'Post Type General Name' ),
                'singular_name'       => _x( 'Termin', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
                'menu_name'           => __( 'TERMINE'),
                'all_items'           => __( 'Alle Termine'),
                'view_item'           => __( 'Termin anzeigen'),
                'add_new_item'        => __( 'Termin hinzufügen'),
                'add_new'             => __( 'Neuer Termin'),
                'edit_item'           => __( 'Termin bearbeiten'),
                'update_item'         => __( 'Aktualisiere Termin'),
                'search_items'        => __( 'Termin suchen'),
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array ('post_tag', 'category'),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array ( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
            'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'termine')
        )
    );
}
```

The question: why is the fourth custom post type not showing up, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it. I was sure WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php was set to true, but it wasn't. So after changing this I got a message saying that 20 characters is maximum for a post type name.

> [Sun Apr 08 18:29:44.083267 2018] [:error] [pid 5901] [client
>   127.0.0.1:45860] PHP Notice:  register_post_type wurde **fehlerhaft aufgerufen**. Der Name eines Inhaltstyps
>   muss aus mindestens einem und maximal 20 Zeichen bestehen. Weitere
>   Informationen: Debugging in
>   WordPress (engl.) (Diese Meldung wurde in Version 4.2.0
>   hinzugef\xc3\xbcgt.) in /var/www/rpc/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   4147, referer:
>   http://rpc.lkl/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=all&paged=1&s

I chose a shorter name, and now it shows up!